# Runtime exception : Laminas error in system log

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.5p1

I am getting the following error in the backend.

main.CRITICAL: Laminas\Escaper\Exception\RuntimeException: String to be escaped was not valid UTF-8 or could not be converted: [$ 1$][$ 2$] in /var/www/html/vendor/laminas/laminas-escaper/src/Escaper.php:360

This is causing image uploads to be slow in the admin backend.

Can anyone let me know the solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Please run the below command hope this help you.

```
composer require laminas/laminas-escaper:2.7.0
```